# 希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者など

Tags: grammar

> 出生も不明、実在したかどうかさえ不明瞭。
>   ただ人々の口端にのみ上り、**希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者など**、この世でおそらくただ一人。
>   佐々木小次郎と呼ばれるモノを討ち果たした、史実に残らぬ宿敵のみ。
>
> Birth place unknown, whether he really existed or not also unknown.
>   Only, he became a rumor among the people, the one who knows him as a swordsman with an excellent mastership of kendou and was his rival, in this world there is only one I am afraid.
>   The one who killed the man known as Sasaki Koujiro, the enemy who did not remain in formal history.

希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者など
希代の剣豪の好敵手として=As a rival with incredible mastership in kendou
祭り上げられた=To set up as someone with an high social status or position (passive)
剣士=Warrior
希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士=The warrior who was set up as a rival with an incredible mastership in kendou
を=Direct Object
知る=To know
希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を=The warrior who was set up as a rival with an incredible mastership in kendou (who is receiveing the action of being 知る)
者=Man  (In this case I believe he is doing the action of knowing)
希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者=The man who knows the warrior who was set up as a rival (his rival) with an incredible mastership in kendou
など=And such (It makes this the topic for the rest of the sentence)

Do I understand this sentence correctly?

Comment: One thing I must say is, kendou mostly stands for a kind of peaceful martial art that doesn't use real weapon. 剣豪 is rather a swordmaster with bladed sword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your breakdown at the bottom seems basically fine to me.

> 希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者
>   the man who knows the swordsman who was set up as a rival to the great sword master (of the day).

However, your translation written at the top seems inconsistent with this. And `ただ人々の口端にのみ上り、希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた` all modifies 剣士 as a relative clause.

In addition, など in this context is not "and such," but a particle which emphasizes the sentence. ([more examples here](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=nado%3B%20nanka%3B%20nante)).

> ただ人々の口端にのみ上り、希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者など、この世でおそらくただ一人。
>   There is probably only one man who knows the swordsman who only appears in rumors and was set up as a rival to the great sword master.

---

By the way, are these sentences fiction? The person who is said to have defeated Sasaki Kojiro is [Miyamoto Musashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyamoto_Musashi), and he certainly existed.

Comment: Yes, they are fiction.